# What kind of regex should I use for the following template?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a Java program that calculates a person's average salary, and prints the monthly deductions in a template. The template is something like this:

```
==============BILL==============
|  NAME: xXxX     BRANCH : xxx |
|                              |
|    Month 1 : xxx.xxx         |
|    Month 2 : xxxx.xx         |
|     <other Months>           |
|    Month 12 : xxx.xx         |
|                              |
|     TOTAL : ____________     |
================================
```

I am using the following pattern to try and capture the elements:

```
//template is stored in string.
String[] lines = msg.split("\n");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[xX\\._]+");
for(String line : lines){
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("no match found...");
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is something like this:

```
xXxX
xxx.xxx
xxxx.xx
xxx.xx
____________
```

However, I'm not able to match the 'xxx' of BRANCH. How do I extract that pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

to

```
while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

as `NAME` and `BRANCH` are on the same line.

`Matcher#find()` will find first match in string, not all matches. To get all matches you have to call `find()` multiple times.

Comment: Thank you! Just a small follow up question - how do I replace these matched tokens? I'm relatively new to RegEx, so please forgive me if I sound gullible

Comment: `stringToAlter.replace(m.group(),"WhateverAlterContent")`;

Comment: Is the following the right way?

    for(...){
        if(line[i].contains("somePattern")){
            line[i] = line[i].replace(m.group(),"myReplacement");
        }
    }

Comment: `String#contains` accepts char pattern (exact pattern) but not regex FYI. But in general yes it is fine. You can always skip `contains` check and simply do `replaceAll`. It accepts regex as argument and if there is no match - for that check you are using `contains` nothing will be replace - `String#contains` becomes surplus.